# VB.Net access other form without creating a new one

Tags: vb.net

Newb question.  I'm coming form VB6 where to access another form you would simply use
`form2.textbox.text = x`

In VB.net I've read to use

```
Dim newform As New Form2()
```

`newform.textbox.text = x`

This creates a new form each time.  I would like to have only one instance of this form and be able to recall data off it at a later time.  What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: VB 6 or VB.NET? They are very different things

Comment: You need to clearly understand the difference between an INSTANCE of an object and the DEFINITION for that object. VB6 gave you default form instances you could access through their type name. This muddled that concept. VB.Net makes a cleaner distinction. If you could have **many** instances of your `form2` type on the screen at a time, it makes sense to require you to be more explicit about what object you are using. Additionally, VB.Net has real OOP objects, including a better concept of private members. All form properties are private by default, but you can change that to Public.

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to solve this.

You could create the instance of `Form2` as a property on a Module (specific to VB), or you could implement the Singleton pattern, which is a more generic approach.

Either way, the idea is to maintain a reference to your second form within the scope of the other form(s), and simply call `form2.ShowDialog()` or `form2.Show()` when needed.

EDIT:

For the sake of completenes, here's a minimalist implementation of Singleton for `Form2`:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Shared _instance As Form2
    Private Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetInstance() As Form2

        If _instance Is Nothing Then
            _instance = New Form2()
        End If

        Return _instance

    End Function


End Class
```

Then in another form, for example here in a `Button` click handler, you'd get the Singleton instance like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Form2.GetInstance().ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

The thing to note is that `Form2`'s constructor is private so that the only way to instantiate it is through the Shared Function.

Comment: anyway you can point me to an example of each? thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Good old Google: http://vbnotebookfor.net/2007/09/13/introduction-to-the-singleton-pattern-in-vbnet/

Answer (score 0):

1. you are developing WinForm application. so when Form2 is not showing, and you are trying to assign a value to one of its control's property might not be a good idea. From Form2, you can always get the calling form's property or control status.
2. to show Form2, you don't have to create an instance of it, simply call: Form2.Showdialog() will open it. I am assuming you've already added the Form2 file under the solution tree.